# How to remove diagonal white lines on openlayers-3 with Bing maps as source in google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bing-maps, openlayers-3

I used openlayers-3 in rendering Bing maps and it was displaying completely fine in FF but diagonal white lines appear on the map if I use google-chrome. How can I remove the white lines on google-chrome? I use google-chrome version 55.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[sample map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fh2e.png)

Comment: Same problem here, but it seems to work fine with the 4.1.0 version of OpenLayers.